# Is a good practice to request db data on controller when using ORM?

Tags: model-view-controller, sequelize.js

When using ORMs is it a good practice do things like model-instance.findAll() on a controllers?

Comment: It depends. Can you show us an example of when you are thinking of using it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the Sequelize ORM in a controller would be considered good practice, assuming it is implemented correctly - error handling, etc.

**Example:**

```
// `models` should contain model definitions

function MyController(app) {
  const controller = this;

  controller.getRecord = async (id, options) => {
    try {
      const records = await models.ModelName.findById(
        where: {
          id,
        },
      });
      // do more things
      return records;
    } catch (err) {
      // handle the error
      return err;
    }
  };

  return controller;
}

module.exports = MyController;
```